# Is there a functional way to remove duplicate items in a multi dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, functional-programming

Is there a functional way to the following?

I wanted to use array_filter but I can't think of a way to build up a $ids_used array within the array_filter callback.

```
    $data = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'price' => 5,
        ],
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'price' => 6,
        ]
    ];

    $ids_used = [];
    foreach($data as $index => $item)
    {
        if(in_array($item['id'], $ids_used)) {
            unset($data[$index]);
        }
        else
        {
            $ids_used[] = $item['id'];
        }
    }

// expected output is: $data = [['id' => 1,'price' => 5]];
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like? Because it is do-able to only have the 1 `id` set - [Example](https://eval.in/335963)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you just want to wrap it in array_filter:

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'price' => 5,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'price' => 6,
    ]
];
$ids_used = [];
$filtered = array_filter($data, function($item) use (&$ids_used) {

    if(!in_array($item['id'], $ids_used)) {
        $ids_used[] = $item['id'];
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

});
var_dump($ids_used);
var_dump($filtered);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use reference feature and closure feature of anonymous functions.

```
$ids_used = [];
$result = array_filter($data, function($item)use(&$ids_used)
    {
    if (in_array($item['id'], $ids_used))
        {
        return false;
        }
    else
        {
        $ids_used[] = $item['id'];
        return true;
        }
    });

var_dump($result);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php